# Text or percentage in circular progress indicator flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I add **Text or percentage** in [![circular progress indicator][1]][1] flutter, like **Loading or 78%**,, for more clear information I attached an image.

How can I add **Text or percentage** in [![circular progress indicator][1]][1] flutter, like **Loading or 78%**,, for more clear information I attached an image.

How can I add **Text or percentage** in [![circular progress indicator][1]][1] flutter, like **Loading or 78%**,, for more clear information I attached an image.

````
    import 'package:photo_view/photo_view.dart';
    import 'package:photo_view/photo_view_gallery.dart';
    import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';
    
    class Margalla_View_Housing_Scheme extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _Margalla_View_Housing_SchemeState createState() => _Margalla_View_Housing_SchemeState();
    }
    class _Margalla_View_Housing_SchemeState extends State<Margalla_View_Housing_Scheme> {
      final imageList = [
        'https://www.arteffectconsultants.com/maps/Islamabad/Margala%20View%20Housing.jpg',
      ];
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
            title: Text("Margalla View Housing Scheme"),
          ),
          // add this body tag with container and photoview widget
          body: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                height: 800,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 20,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: PhotoViewGallery.builder(
                        itemCount: imageList.length,
                        builder: (context, index) {
                          return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
                            basePosition: Alignment.center,
                            imageProvider: NetworkImage(imageList[index]),
                            minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 0.8,
                            maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered * 5,
    
                          );
                        },
                        scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                          color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                        ),
                        enableRotation:true,
                        loadingBuilder: (context, event) => Center(
                          child: Container(
                            width: 90.0,
                            height: 90.0,
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              strokeWidth: 9.0,
                              backgroundColor:Colors.orange,
                              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.deepPurple),
                              // semanticsLabel: "Downloading file abc.mp3",
                              // semanticsValue: "Percent " + (100).toString() + "%",
                              value: event == null
                                  ? 0
                                  : event.cumulativeBytesLoaded / event.expectedTotalBytes,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBLBV.png
````

Answer (score 4):

I cannot understand your problem fully, however you may want to check : https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator

You can simply use that like

```
CircularPercentIndicator(
              radius: 60.0,
              lineWidth: 5.0,
              percent: 1.0,
              center: new Text("100%"),
              progressColor: Colors.green,
            )
```

Comment: But dose not show the loading or the image after loading complete, it generate just a static  page.

Comment: When image is loading you can change Text with setState. Use a variable inside Text. Check : https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-show-download-progress-in-a-flutter-app-8810e294acbd

Comment: Problem still did't solved, can you please add it to my code!

Answer (score 0):

There is a native way to do that in Flutter without using third party packages - CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive constructor. In order to add percentage text in the center, we can combine it with Stack widget:

```
Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
         CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(
              value: 0.5,
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
              
            ),
            Center(
                      child: Text(
                    '50%',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  )),
         ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a Column or Stack component to add other Text because CircularProgressIndicator doesn't have any text property or similar

Take advantage of the event properties.

```
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view.dart';
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view_gallery.dart';
// ...


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
      child: PhotoViewGallery.builder(
        scrollPhysics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
            imageProvider: AssetImage(widget.galleryItems[index].image),
            initialScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 0.8,
            heroAttributes: PhotoViewHeroAttributes(tag: galleryItems[index].id),
          );
        },
        itemCount: galleryItems.length,
        loadingBuilder: (context, event) => Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 20.0,
            height: 20.0,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text( "Progress: ${event.cumulativeBytesLoaded /( event.expectedTotalBytes?? 1)} %"),
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                  value: event == null
                      ? 0
                      : event.cumulativeBytesLoaded / (event.expectedTotalBytes?? 1),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundDecoration: widget.backgroundDecoration,
        pageController: widget.pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
      )
  );
}
```